# Error con JSON.Parse con barras invertidas

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Holas buenas tardes.

Estoy teniendo problemas al pasear un json en javascript con `JSON.parse`.

Desde el servidor me devuelve un json string como el que esta abajo, pero cuando hago JSON.parse me da el siguiente error error .

Por lo que veo es por `"video" : "\\EUY-SER-AOE\VIDEO\\10\08202003\1010829821030929F.mp4"`, ya que quitando eso lo hace correctamente. Hay alguna forma de poder solucionar esto?. Ya pobre de reemplazar cada `\` por `\\` pero sigue igual.

El lenguaje que uso en el servidor es C#.

El json devuleto es:

```
{
 "est" : "10", 
 "Via" : "1", 
 "Sentido" : "D", 
 "tab" : "2", 
 "det" : "2", 
 "consol" : "2", 
 "tag" : "N", 
 "video" : "\\EUY-SER-AOE\VIDEO\\10\08202003\1010829821030929F.mp4", 
 "Evento" : "111111111111", 
 "tck" : "", 
 "parte" : "111111111", 
 "Modo" : "Dinámica"
 }
```

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: El problema es que tienes algunos \ sin escapar: `\\EUY-SER-AOE\VIDEO\\10\08202003\1010829821030929F.mp4` y pueden ser interpretados como secuencia octal, por lo que la misma cadena (antes de JSON.parse()) no tiene un valor apropiado. ¿Generas el JSON manualmente o usas alguna clase como [JsonResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0)?

Comment: Grácias por la respuesta. Lo hago manualmente. No es que algunos \  están sin escapar, ya viene de la base de datos así, tiene \\ y \.

Answer (score 0):

Con la clase [JsonResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0), automáticamente se van a escapar todos los caracteres que necesiten ser escapados, por lo que es tu mejor opción.

Pero, si aún lo quieres hacer manualmente, remplaza en el servidor `\` por `/`. Si vas a usar la ruta en una etiqueta `<video>` o una petición AJAX funcionará con las diagonales normales y, si por alguna razón necesitas las diagonales invertidas, es muy fácil remplazar para tener nuevamente el valor original:

```js
let str = `{
 "est" : "10", 
 "Via" : "1", 
 "Sentido" : "D", 
 "tab" : "2", 
 "det" : "2", 
 "consol" : "2", 
 "tag" : "N", 
 "video" : "//EUY-SER-AOE/VIDEO//10/08202003/1010829821030929F.mp4", 
 "Evento" : "111111111111", 
 "tck" : "", 
 "parte" : "111111111", 
 "Modo" : "Dinámica"
}`;

let obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj);

// Remplazar diagonales
let video = obj.video.replaceAll('/', '\\');
console.log(video);
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las respuestas. Lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera: en vez de generar el string manualmente, cree un diccionary<string,string> y los fui agregando ahí. Después con Javascript serializer lo serialize y ahí lo escapó bien.